# Yii:Getting a dropdown button with options in it

Tags: php, html, yii

I have this code for my header which has the login and sign in button. I want that upon login the sign-up button should disappear and username is displayed(as it is already happening) and a drop down button by the name options which has a logout button and a profile button in it. Please help, thank you.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row logo">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
           <br>
           <a href='<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php'><p>ERS.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <br>
          <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/user/registration"><p class='pull-right'>SignUp</p></a>
                                        <!--to show the username and logout button in the header upon login-->
  <?php  
   if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
       echo  "<a href='" .  Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 
       "/user/login'><p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>LogIn</p></a>";
    }
    if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
           echo  '<span style="color: white; font-style: italic; font-size:20px; margin-left:550px">'. Yii::app()->user->name .  "</span> <a href='" .  
                Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . 
                 "/site/logout' ><p class='pull-right' style='margin-right: 12px'>Logout</p></a>";
        }
    ?>

     </div>
   </div><!--row ending here-->
   <div class="row navigation">
     <br>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php"><p>Home</p></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ngo/allngo"><p>Ngo's</p></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/blog/allblog"><p>Blogs</p></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/story/allstory"><p>Stories</p></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/event/allevent"><p>Events</p></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/"><p>Report</p></a></li>
       </ul>
        <br>
     </div>
   </div><!--row ending here-->                                  
 </div> <!--header ending here-->
<!-- <div class="row">
      <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div>-->
```